# Find all parent id's in array in C

Tags: c

I have  to find all parents, for example i search all PID and PPID with id 10.

If PID has id, for example let's take 10,  I print `printf("%d %d", PID[i], PPID[i])` and it's done.

Problem is if PPID has id 10, then I also print it (`printf("%d %d",PID[j],PPID[j])`), but now I also have to find all PID and PPID with new id PID[J]. example PPID with id 10 is at index 3 , i print (PID[3] , PPID[3]) and also on index 7 . PID[3] is 13 and PID[7] is 31 so now i have 2 new IDS and have to repat procedure.

I don't know how to program that. Probably recursive function? But don't know how to write it (when to stop it and how to call).

I did try with loops (non recursive) but my program got stuck, should i also put that code here?
If writing with  loops i need some kind of stack

```
#include<stdio.h>

int recursion() {  
    return 0;
}  

int main() {
    int PID[10]={1,15,10,13,44,28,30,31,50,17};
    int PPID[10]={0,3,20,10,18,7,13,10,30,47};
    int findID=10; 

    recursion();

    //result should be following pairs: 10|20 ; 13|10 ; 30|13 ; 31|10 ; 50|30
}
```

Comment: For clarity purposes, do you want to find `PID[i]` alongside `PPID[j]`? + your second paragraph is not cleared.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and your question is vague. You should clarify what you've tried, want to do and what the current results are

Comment: Why do you want to use `recursion` ?

Comment: I taught it would be better/ easier  with recursion,  Tho i tried with loops, but it didn't work, my program got stuck printing only PID of  PPID of base value until it crashed

Answer (score 0):

if the PID and PPID array sizes are in same, the Answer is as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void find(int id,int arr1 [],int arr2 [],int size,int notId) { 
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if((arr1[i]==id || arr2[i]==id) && arr1[i]!=notId && arr2[i]!=notId) {
            printf(" %d | %d;",arr1[i],arr2[i]);
            if(arr1[i]!=id){
              find(arr1[i],arr1,arr2,size,id);
            }
        }
    }

}  

int main() {
    int PID[10]={1,15,10,13,44,28,30,31,50,17};
    int PPID[10]={0,3,20,10,18,7,13,10,30,47};
    int size = sizeof(PID)/sizeof(PID[0]);
    int findID=10; 
    find(findID,PID,PPID,size,0);
    return 0;
}
```